# Regex: How to find attribute in html, that includes another attribute

Tags: python, html, regex, beautifulsoup

In this HTML code:

```
<frameset border="0" framespacing="0" frameborder="0" rows="85,*">
<frame border="0" marginheight="0" name="logoframe" scrolling="no" noresize target="middle" src="a.html" onload="reload()">

<frameset cols="235,*">
<frame border="0" name="left" src="b.html" scrolling="no"><frame border="0" noresize name="main" src="c.html"  scrolling="auto"></frameset><noframes>
<body topmargin="0" leftmargin="0">
<p>This page uses frames, but your browser doesn't support them.</p></body>         
</noframes>
</frameset></html>
```

I want to find the `src` attribute that contains `name="main"`
in this example it should return `c.html`.

Comment: Do *not* parse HTML with regex. Seriously.

Comment: a solution with beautifulsoup will be good too

Comment: More options: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=python+dom+parser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#beautiful-soup-documentation) as follows:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<frameset border="0" framespacing="0" frameborder="0" rows="85,*">
<frame border="0" marginheight="0" name="logoframe" scrolling="no" noresize target="middle" src="a.html" onload="reload()">

<frameset cols="235,*">
<frame border="0" name="left" src="b.html" scrolling="no"><frame border="0" noresize name="main" src="c.html"  scrolling="auto"></frameset><noframes>
<body topmargin="0" leftmargin="0">
<p>This page uses frames, but your browser doesn't support them.</p></body>         
</noframes>
</frameset></html>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

frame = soup.find('frame', attrs={'name': 'main'})
print frame['src']
```

It will display the text:

```
c.html
```

Answer (score 0):

Using JQuery you can simply do that as below,

```
var srcFetched = $("input[name='main']").attr("src");
alert(srcFetched);
```

Comment: I can do something similar with beautifulsoup ?

Answer (score 0):

Best to use **HTML or XML parser** to **extract** values from the **HTML or XML** content, **regular expression** are good, but still I will prefer Parser to extract data from the html content.

As someone give answer by [`Beautifulsoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).

Following is by [`lxml`](http://lxml.de/) parser

**Demo**:

```
>>> from lxml import html as PARSER 
>>> root = PARSER.fromstring(html)
>>> root.xpath("//frame")
[<Element frame at 0xb748e414>, <Element frame at 0xb748eb94>, <Element frame at 0xb748e5a4>]
>>> root.xpath("//frame[@name='main']")
[<Element frame at 0xb748e5a4>]
>>> root.xpath("//frame[@name='main']/@src")
['c.html']
>>>
```

in above code,

1. we create object by `fromstring` method
2. Use [`xpath`](http://lxml.de/extensions.html) mothod to find target value and tag.
3. Used condition in `xpath` to get target data.